# ¿Cómo puedo dejar habilitada una conexión de red local de manera automática?

Tags: python, sqlite3, samba

Tengo una App hecha en python que deseo que trabaje con una base de datos (sqlite3) en una raspberry pi con Raspbian y q le instalé samba.
Si yo ingreso desde mi PC a la carpeta compartida de la RPi, y luego uso mi App, funciona correctamente. Pero una vez que reinicio la PC, la App deja de funcionar sin poderse conectar con la bd, hasta que vuelvo a ingresar de manera normal a su carpeta compartida.
¿Existe alguna manera de que mi App simule ese "ingreso previo" a la carpeta compartida ingresando el usuario y contraseña para que quede establecida la conexión y luego poder hacer uso habitual del programa?.
No quisiera como usuario tener que ingresar todos los días de manera manual a la carpeta compartida, desde ya, muchas gracias!

Comment: ¿Qué sistema operativo tiene tu PC? ¿Windows, Linux o Mac?

Comment: Adicionalmente: usar una `SQLite` (que es un simple archivo) mediante una unidad compartida es una **extremadamente mala idea**. Intenta arrancar 2 instancias de tu aplicación y usar a la vez la BBDD y nos cuentas :-)

Comment: Programo en Windows 10 pero compilo los programas en la plataforma en que se va a usar, en éste caso Raspbian, es una de las versiones de Linux para las Raspberry Pi.
Se que es mala idea, pero son 2 PCs conectadas en red sin acceso a internet. Cuando pueda haré algo más seguro, mientras tanto necesito hacerlo funcionar lo antes posible.